# got the following symbol � in my sql

Tags: mysql

got the following symbol � in my sql 
i want to know the source of it 
and how could i remove it automatically 
manual takes a lot of time

https://postimg.cc/gXK3HfX7

---

i got the following symbol after convert database to UTF-8
10.2.22-MariaDB

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the MySQL version(x,y,z)? And where you got that symbol. I mean to say that after export of MySQL data in excel format or elsewhere inside the table data .

Comment: That just looks like a character encoding issue where the encoding that is set in the database/ide is unable to store what is actually in that record in the database.

Comment: What was the original input data? And what character set were you converting to UTF8 from?

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored